# How do I set Origin Path in Azure CDN using Resouce Manager API?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-cdn

I want to tell the Azure CDN that my origin is at a specific path, e.g. `mydomain.com/cdn`. This option is available through the Azure Portal (CDN Profile > Endpoint > Configure > Origin path)

I'm deploying my Azure resources using Resource Manager APIs and Json templates. However, I can't find this setting in the template here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-cdn-customize

Is this not available or am I missing something?

**Update**
Using the Resource Explorer, I found the property on the endpoints node with a `null`. Even if I try to set the value (and the API accepts it), the value is not set.

```
    {
      "value": [
        {
          "name": "<hidden>",
          "id": "/subscriptions/<hidden>/resourcegroups/<hidden>/providers/Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/<hidden>/endpoints/<hidden>",
          "type": "Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/endpoints",
          "tags": {},
          "location": "NorthEurope",
          "properties": {
            "hostName": "<hidden>",
            "originHostHeader": "<hidden>",
            "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
            "resourceState": "Running",
            "isHttpAllowed": true,
            "isHttpsAllowed": true,
            "queryStringCachingBehavior": "UseQueryString",
            "originPath": null,
            "origins": [
              {
                "name": "<hidden>",
                "properties": {
                  "hostName": "<hidden>",
                  "httpPort": null,
                  "httpsPort": null
                }
              }
            ],
            "contentTypesToCompress": [
              "application/x-javascript",
              "text/css",
              "text/html",
              "text/javascript",
              "text/plain"
            ],
            "isCompressionEnabled": false
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited 4/15/2016 to correct the code insert**

Since that is an optional configuration, the template may not have it.
The portion from azuredeploy.json line 97, appears to be configuring CDN endpoint. Adding the line 104 as below should help.

```
 97      "properties": {
 98      "originHostHeader": "[parameters('originUrl')]",
 99      "isHttpAllowed": "[parameters('isHttpAllowed')]",
 100     "isHttpsAllowed": "[parameters('isHttpsAllowed')]",
 101     "queryStringCachingBehavior": "[parameters('queryStringCachingBehavior')]",
 102     "contentTypesToCompress": "[parameters('contentTypesToCompress')]",
 103     "isCompressionEnabled": "[parameters('isCompressionEnabled')]",
 104     "originPath": "[parameters('originPath')]",
 105     "origins": [
 106     {
 107       "name": "origin1",
 108       "properties": {
 109         "hostName": "[parameters('originUrl')]"
 110
 111       }
 112     }
 113   ]
```

Of course you will need to add this block in your parameter file

```
        "originPath": {
        "value": "/cdn"
    }
```

Hopefully this would work out for you

Comment: Your guidance got me thinking and I used the Resource Explorer to see what I could find. Under the endpoint properties, there is actually a `originPath` property. Unfortunately, any change to this value is not persisted.

Comment: Thanks for the update and output. I was wrong, it's not a sub-property of origins, it's directly attached to parent. If you insert `"originPath": "[parameters('originPath')]",` bewteen line 103 and 104 instead, it should work. Edited the answer reflect to this change

Comment: I finally got this to work. Perhaps the issue was that I updated an existing endpoint. When creating a new endpoint, the setting does work.